# How do I display the console on counter strike GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I thought i had to push the ~ or ` key to open the console but my PC simply ignores the command. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Usually, it's in the options somewhere (I don't know specifically, I'm speaking generally for Source games)

Answer (score 15):

You have to go to the Game settings and check the `enable developer console`. After this you can use ` or the assigned key to open and close it.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, it says "`" on my MacBook, but it's actually §. Weird.

Comment: @grooveplex Thanks! What I wanted to know! 

Answer (score 1):

Source: http://fearless-assassins.com/tutorials/article/268-csgo-how-to-enable-console/

Start game -> Help & Options -> Game Settings -> make sure you have this enabled(There is an image in the source link for the page you are looking for)

Then You can go to Help & Options -> Keyboard/mouse -> and change your console key. The  default is " ` "(Tilde Key).

Hopefully this helps.